# Cucumber with Capybara, how to embed screenshot into report for each step?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I know how to take screenshot after a failed scenario, but how do I take screenshot after each step and embed it in report?

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  screenshot =  "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}.png"
  page.save_screenshot(screenshot)
  embed(screenshot, "image/png", "SCREENSHOT")
  FileUtils.rm_rf(screenshot)
end
```

The screenshot is saved successfully, but embed method does not exist in that context. I know embed method is defined in the reporter class, how do I get hold of the reporter class in the hooks?

Comment: correction, the embed method is defined but somewhere down the line an exception " undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass>" is thrown.

Comment: I think this was caused by the scenario where browser can't reach the home page of the application being tested.

Answer (score 0):

actually my question was invalid.

the embed method does exist in AfterStep hook. the problem I had was probably related to some browser startup issue.